# Modify markers/lines for two legends separately in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend

My plot below consists of contour lines from a density estimate and several points, which are colored by the number of experiments. The legend for the contour lines is indicated by the alpha values, which is based on the level of the contour. The legend for the points are based on color and shape. When I try to modify the size of the points in the second legend, it also modifies the points for the first (level) legend. I'd like to

1. Remove the markers in the level legend and keep only the lines.
2. Remove the lines in the points legend (Num. Experiments) and keep only the markers.

I tried to use the grid package to modify the elements, but I'm lost as two what element in the grobs I should be extracting.

```
 plt <- ggplot() +
  facet_grid(Ylab~subtype)+
  geom_point(data=subset(All_subtypes_CD27_57_45,disc_comb_label>0),
             aes(x=CD45RO,y=Y,
                 color=factor(disc_comb_label),
                 shape=factor(disc_comb_label)),
             size=0.3,stroke=0.4,alpha=0.7,show.legend = TRUE) +
  stat_density_2d(data=subset(All_subtypes_CD27_57_45,disc_comb_label==0),
                  geom = "density2d", contour = TRUE,
                  aes(x=CD45RO,y=Y,alpha=..level..),
                  color = "black",
                  bins = 20,
                  show.legend=TRUE) +
  labs(col="Num. Experiments",shape="Num. Experiments") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())

plt
grid::grid.ls(grid::grid.force())

# Set the size of the point in the legend to 4 mm
grid::grid.gedit("key-[-0-9]-1-1", size = unit(4, "mm"))

# save the modified plot to an object
plt2 <- grid::grid.grab()
ggsave(plt2, filename = 'plt2.jpg')
```

[image: Example Plot]

**Edit**

Here is a sample (n=100) of my data. Note: the `bins` parameter in `stat_density_2d` should be changed to a smaller number.

```
structure(list(Y = c(0.284191844029658, 0.558504950709616, 0.315535249343904, 
0.300977792187569, 0.476751857332456, 0.484240073554636, 0.307618222739758, 
0.382774310068314, 0.251491191205721, 0.28867075547189, 0.48023653568676, 
0.687385202552218, 0.348302145404881, 0.284956590469867, 0.449212367426197, 
0.0541572395716273, 0.43091149290646, 0.475086982205484, 0.245475455526474, 
0.320922298535602, 0.433582014376387, 0.454556959163362, 0.519150252727787, 
0.501333864070255, 0.485212214204431, 0.477742661471719, 0.141047727372665, 
0.455451223886891, 0.445897410519097, 0.405296464170209, 0.383655314069156, 
0.213964454993715, 0.242076596187618, 0.298039605455974, 0.157815389237226, 
0.510987159437738, 0.228542986920969, 0.348112572853986, 0.149900990492508, 
0.390457313763976, 0.530735405696848, 0.213071719254767, 0.241746672739817, 
0.109465638906155, 0.2119121647415, 0.252433268896037, 0.271972455301221, 
0.434829111969484, 0.139716827881697, 0.342203160239369, 0.604210909752249, 
0.161481369781311, 0.514151082252664, 0.826880955040602, 0.278455388719208, 
0.457955173141471, 0.223481509755878, 0.281433841010683, 0.265601344949778, 
0.272361939825042, 0.36767244848865, 0.200105787104064, 0.297752168002793, 
0.188282485134585, 0.33643615610689, 0.395965507439215, 0.0890174556246681, 
0.417612455377232, 0.19887950366616, 0.465049525577064, 0.43789996897205, 
0.233188419733737, 0.472491498664791, 0.490773751335154, 0.283266705976633, 
0.401634634651268, 0.45359606927769, 0.20839301810666, 0.441058569024316, 
0.276163969969656, 0.431188894873133, 0.237522516690592, 0.233077805700025, 
0.297329147941213, 0.42710702221155, 0.3907243000129, 0.465552001533375, 
0.437707004564491, 0.384245170961772, 0.142554943891278, 0.435330262145555, 
0.284103620665539, 0.2032116293577, 0.414955141708168, 0.345017391130214, 
0.248463896517405, 0.339817523912329, 0.459771971558186, 0.468755486667213, 
0.510785855184823), CD45RO = c(0.525726398529141, 0.304474523564729, 
0.612153302344189, 0.612445867565633, 0.249006124636231, 0.0630792385460927, 
0.634621606796433, 0.252505566525164, 0.58427415301859, 0.604953653422854, 
0.59367781186968, 0.548146880829038, 0.67686535460711, 0.079010054101595, 
0.634599315045999, 0.13187972282609, 0.621565232085858, 0.596574983786016, 
0.110399227872914, 0.658258800443354, 0.187991482962981, 0.650987717469758, 
0.596006502059151, 0.308912127599816, 0.141884410965155, 0.114224151171362, 
0.190296706882678, 0.0868622977334288, 0.63084574911242, 0.584149459993462, 
0.565119489277156, 0.262145879230163, 0.275739650088701, 0.628409611625278, 
0.106602930270878, 0.107132119095279, 0.620913668866589, 0.624362488858585, 
0.233756876594812, 0.655615553883786, 0.54873101008282, 0.566443932082788, 
0.561891801854012, 0.621932759341326, 0.552259106473471, 0.56920228491713, 
0.602947665552384, 0.696337649780824, 0.660389489026038, 0.584038886021908, 
0.468975660037085, 0.333155729501406, 0.0495060776252205, 0.16990324928303, 
0.193105192142293, 0.181173895819966, 0.150182889940719, 0.543052295456474, 
0.283001532733579, 0.303728587073113, 0.183658577822127, 0.592509419580238, 
0.714762268117432, 0.128905862697456, 0.638109641089135, 0.654036824302771, 
0.339947661585455, 0.594245937801801, 0.490577748124374, 0.22853081037735, 
0.185257260802601, 0.533315410258717, 0.626633178546256, 0.199126070652748, 
0.188082776802629, 0.635724850685052, 0.638027785005966, 0.608592892283015, 
0.613768324429073, 0.680925083206514, 0.722032485457904, 0.143070125871505, 
0.633443738551264, 0.308183097921232, 0.619142922059335, 0.335770730782286, 
0.291214123731697, 0.142393299180996, 0.252553809505749, 0.423003230545203, 
0.568276957780311, 0.484324230817047, 0.285551015338659, 0.524580106114011, 
0.680325288283035, 0.348542443973256, 0.581367577522363, 0.321724942946382, 
0.0778090215803436, 0.231216025188849), disc_comb_label = c(2, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 
5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 6, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2), Ylab = c("CD27", 
"CD57", "CD57", "CD57", "CD27", "CD27", "CD57", "CD27", "CD27", 
"CD27", "CD27", "CD57", "CD57", "CD57", "CD27", "CD57", "CD27", 
"CD27", "CD57", "CD27", "CD27", "CD27", "CD27", "CD27", "CD27", 
"CD27", "CD57", "CD27", "CD27", "CD27", "CD57", "CD57", "CD57", 
"CD57", "CD57", "CD27", "CD27", "CD27", "CD57", "CD27", "CD27", 
"CD57", "CD27", "CD57", "CD57", "CD27", "CD57", "CD57", "CD57", 
"CD27", "CD57", "CD57", "CD27", "CD57", "CD57", "CD27", "CD57", 
"CD57", "CD57", "CD27", "CD57", "CD27", "CD57", "CD57", "CD27", 
"CD27", "CD57", "CD27", "CD27", "CD27", "CD27", "CD57", "CD27", 
"CD27", "CD57", "CD27", "CD27", "CD57", "CD57", "CD57", "CD27", 
"CD27", "CD57", "CD57", "CD27", "CD57", "CD27", "CD57", "CD57", 
"CD57", "CD27", "CD57", "CD57", "CD57", "CD57", "CD27", "CD27", 
"CD27", "CD27", "CD27"), subtype = c("CD4-CD8+", "CD4+CD8+", 
"CD4-CD8+", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8+", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8+", "CD4-CD8+", 
"CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8+", "CD4+CD8+", "CD4+CD8+", "CD4+CD8+", "CD4-CD8+", 
"CD4+CD8-", "CD4-CD8+", "CD4-CD8+", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8-", 
"CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4-CD8+", "CD4-CD8+", "CD4+CD8+", 
"CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4-CD8+", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8+", 
"CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8+", "CD4+CD8+", "CD4+CD8+", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8+", 
"CD4-CD8+", "CD4-CD8+", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4-CD8+", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8-", 
"CD4+CD8-", "CD4-CD8+", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8+", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4-CD8+", 
"CD4-CD8+", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4-CD8+", "CD4-CD8+", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8+", 
"CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8+", "CD4+CD8+", "CD4-CD8+", "CD4-CD8+", "CD4+CD8+", 
"CD4+CD8+", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8+", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8+", 
"CD4-CD8+", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8+", "CD4-CD8+", 
"CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8+", "CD4+CD8-", 
"CD4+CD8+", "CD4-CD8+", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8+", 
"CD4-CD8+", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4-CD8+", "CD4-CD8+", "CD4+CD8-", 
"CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8-", "CD4-CD8+", "CD4-CD8+", "CD4+CD8-", 
"CD4+CD8-", "CD4+CD8-")), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: OP, can you share with us a `sample()` of your dataset so that the plot can be reproducible?  Type `dput(your_data_frame)` into the console and then paste the output directly into your question (as code) - the result should be something that starts with `structure(...`.  Your dataset is quite large, so you may want to send a sample of *n* rows of that data.  Something like this should be sufficient, if your dataframe is `df`:  `dput(df[sample(1:nrow(df), n),])`.  I'd say 20-50 rows is sufficient to at least create something similar to your plot.

Comment: @chemdork123 - please see my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could leave out the `show.legend = TRUE` to not force the legends to include the layers that are not relevant to the legend.

As an aside, instead of tinkering in the grid system, you can set the points in the legend to a larger size by using the `override.aes` argument in the guide.

Example below (I've named the data included in your question `df`)

```
ggplot() +
  facet_grid(Ylab~subtype)+
  geom_point(data=subset(df,disc_comb_label>0),
             aes(x=CD45RO,y=Y,
                 color=factor(disc_comb_label),
                 shape=factor(disc_comb_label)),
             size=0.3,stroke=0.4,alpha=0.7) +
  stat_density_2d(data=subset(df,disc_comb_label==0),
                  geom = "density2d", contour = TRUE,
                  aes(x=CD45RO,y=Y,alpha=..level..),
                  color = "black",
                  bins = 10) +
  scale_colour_discrete(guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 4))) +
  labs(col="Num. Experiments",shape="Num. Experiments") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! As a quick followup how would I modify the name of the "level" legend?

Comment: You could do `+ scale_alpha(name = "My name here")`